# AS3: Using SWC Shared Library without having to rename packaged class

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to centralize shared assets in a shared library swc. Some of these assets have classes associated with them. An example would be Preloader which has the class Preloader.as.

If I add the swc to the library path, and do not rename the original Preloader.as file to something like _Preloader.as, there will be null errors like crazy.

Or is there a better way to create the swc? Maybe include the assets but not the classes?

Comment: Best way is to have multiple swcs, we used to use stuff like, tweenmax.swc, components.swc, bulkLoader.swc etc. Makes it easy to swap out swcs that are not needed in some projects and avoids naming conflicts as each swc has a full class path.

Comment: Wouldn't this still result in a conflict if your swc class had the same package as the class file? I was thinking the best way to do this would be to separate my ui elements into a different project altogether. That way when I import the swc into my other project those paths wouldn't exist.

Comment: Well yeah class paths shouldn't conflict that's why we have the url as a name space.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance. I think this would still cause a conflict in my case. My swc is technically an unfinished set of ui movieclips and classes. If the project I'm working on links this swc, and still has access to the non-swc'd package, namespaces or not, this would still create a conflict. I think I'm just going to have to create separate projects so that the templates don't have access to the ui classes. Unless there's a way to prioritize class paths.

Comment: You can't prioritize class paths, you must make sure the package names are unique, if you have two classes that have the same name they must be in differently named packages, In you case, can't you put either your unfinished or non-swc components in a different namespace? eg. com.yourwebsite.components.Preloader for new ones?  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9e.html